# Python pyfuzzy problems

Tags: python

When I install pyfuzzy under Windows 7 64 bit, I have this problem:

```
C:\Python27>pip install pyfuzzy
Collecting pyfuzzy
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyfuzzy (from versions: )

Some externally hosted files were ignored as access to them may be unreliable (use --allow-external pyfuzzy to allow).
No matching distribution found for pyfuzzy
```

Someone told me to change the command, but I still meet the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried using the flags the error message suggests?!

Comment: yes but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Download pyfuzzy package from https://github.com/arruda/pyfuzzy
extract it, and `python setup.py install`

Comment: I have download it and use the pip install it , but when i import the module python says Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    import pyfuzzy
ImportError: No module named pyfuzzy

Comment: don't use pip install, download it ,extract it and then python setup.py install

Comment: Thanks a lot. But although it is successfully installed, there'e still problems,the code: import fuzzy    it is no problem ...but when :  soundex = fuzzy.Soundex(4)      it shows  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#30>", line 1, in <module>
    soundex = fuzzy.Soundex(4)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Soundex'       I really don't know why ...